# ASP MVC 5 : How to pass Integer from controller to the view

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, ado.net

I want to call a variable from the controller in my view in ASP MVC 5.

I tried using ViewBag but the variable get Null Value.

This is what I've tried :

**Controller :**

```
     SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("select count (ClientId) from Client", con);
     con.Open();
     string c = command3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     con.Close();                  
     int cc = Convert.ToInt32(c);
     ViewBag.nbre = cc;
```

**View :**

```
  @model IList<Delivery.Models.Client>
  @for (int j=0; j < ViewBag.nbre; j++) {
```

Comment: This should work as expected. How are you calling the View? Please post the full code of the action in the controller.

Comment: @model IList<Delivery.Models.Client>

Comment: Okay, so if you pass the clients to the view, why pass the count through the viewbag rather than call the .Count() in the view?

Comment: In **MVC** you pass data between you **C**ontroller and your **V**iew with a **M**odel. It's like learning your ABC and wondering what comes after B.

Comment: @CodeGhost Many Thanks I don't why I didn't think about it ! it is work with count ! Could you please edit your answer that I can accept it as a solution

Comment: @oerkelens I know but I was missing the connection between the A, the B and C

Comment: @Exact updated my answer

Comment: You really should wrap your SQL in a `using` statement, to implement `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all using the viewbag is [discouraged][1].

As you already send the list to the view, you can simply call the count action there rather than send it through the viewbag

Like so:

```
for(int j =0; j < @Model.Count(); j++) {
```

Comment: the example that you mentionned I already read it and try it but it didn't work to me

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your view use the following code

```
@model Int32
```

in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   int mynumber = 5;
   return View(mynumber);
}
```

then use this in your view, should work no problem

```
@for(int j=0; j < @Model; j==) {

}
```